# there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, entity-relationship

I have created an ER diagram by using PostgreSQL and try to create tables according to exported .sql file but I get an error. I might do a structural fault. If you notice a structural mistake about Entity Relationship Diagram can you explain me?

Error:

[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKxOb.png)

Here is my ER diagram:

[ER DIAGRAM IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y76wZ.png)

Here is my exported SQL Script:

```
BEGIN;


CREATE TABLE public."Persons"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    surname character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    email character varying(30),
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."System_Personals"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Job_Seekers"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    ssn character(11) NOT NULL,
    birth_date date NOT NULL,
    password character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Employers"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    company_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    website character varying(40) NOT NULL,
    phone_number character(11) NOT NULL,
    password character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Jobs"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    role character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    definition character varying(500) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    title character varying(100) NOT NULL,
    company_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    role character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    city_name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    salary bigint NOT NULL,
    job_definition character varying(300) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Cities"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    name character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Activations"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    email character varying(30) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Employer_Activations"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

CREATE TABLE public."Job_Seeker_Activations"
(
    id bigserial NOT NULL,
    ssn character(11) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (id)
);

ALTER TABLE public."System_Personals"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Seekers"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Employers"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."System_Personals"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Jobs" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Employers"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Cities" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (city_name)
    REFERENCES public."Cities" (name)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (role)
    REFERENCES public."Jobs" (role)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_definition)
    REFERENCES public."Jobs" (definition)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Employer_Activations"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Activations" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Seeker_Activations"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (id)
    REFERENCES public."Activations" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Job_Seeker_Activations"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (ssn)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (id)
    NOT VALID;


ALTER TABLE public."Activations"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (email)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (email)
    NOT VALID;

END;
```

Why I get that error? Any help?

Comment: In FK you may reference only unique-constrained columns of reference table. So you need to check your scripts and find where you reference columns other than primary keys (`id`s in your case)

Comment: Which statement gives that error? Try running them one at a time to find the problem statement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of these are in violation:

```sql
ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (city_name)
    REFERENCES public."Cities" (name)
    NOT VALID;

ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (role)
    REFERENCES public."Jobs" (role)
    NOT VALID;

ALTER TABLE public."Job_Announcements"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (job_definition)
    REFERENCES public."Jobs" (definition)
    NOT VALID;

ALTER TABLE public."Activations"
    ADD FOREIGN KEY (email)
    REFERENCES public."Persons" (email)
    NOT VALID;
```

[The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-FK)

> A foreign key must reference columns that either are a primary key or form a unique constraint.